# Does developer API exist for YouTube TV? (tv.youtube.com)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, television

Does Google provide an API for YouTube TV?  (tv.youtube.com)  I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 and it seems to only work for regular youtube.com.

For instance, in my paid YouTube TV account, I have access to "BBC America". Using the https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search API call yields no correct matching results. On the other hand, a search for a free channel such as "France 24" yields an exact match.

Moreover, the search results do not have a field that indicates whether it is paid or free content leading one to believe only free video content shows up in search.

I am hoping a YouTube Google API developer could deliver a definitive answer on whether the capability to get search results for paid video content exists or not.

Comment: Let's wait for the YouTube developers to respond  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209382351